# Change the colour palette in histogram

Tags: r, colors, histogram, ggplot2

I am trying to change the colours of my histogram, but not sure how to do it, that's my code:

```
qplot(user, count, data=count_group, geom="histogram", fill=group,
            xlab = "users", ylab="count", 
            main="Users")+
    opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90, hjust=0, size=7))
```

here is the histogram I get, but the default colours are too bright,

[image]

I would like to use colours like [this](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/ggplot2-qualitative-colour-palettes/)

I tried to add the line, but it didnt work.

```
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = palette)
```

Comment: Did you really added a named `palette`? E.g. adding something like `+scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")` to the end of your line? Or `palette` variable holds something?

Comment: Thanks @daroczig, I solve it this way: +scale_fill_manual(values=heat.colors(19)) 
19 because I have 19 different groups.

Comment: FYI that's a bar chart not a histogram.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use the Brewer Set1 with that many groups, you could do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

count_group <- data.frame(user=factor(rep(1:50, 2)), 
                          count=sample(100, 100, replace=T), 
                          group=factor(rep(LETTERS[1:20], 5)))

library(RColorBrewer)
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
ngroups <- length(unique(count_group$group))
qplot(user, count, data=count_group, geom="histogram", fill=group,
      xlab = "users", ylab="count") +
      opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90, hjust=0, size=7)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = cols(ngroups))
```

[image: Brewer Set 1 with many groups in ggplot]

---

**EDIT**

You can create and use multiple `colorRampPalette`s, e.g. to assign blues to groups A to J and reds to groups K to T:

```
blues <- colorRampPalette(c('dark blue', 'light blue'))
reds <- colorRampPalette(c('pink', 'dark red'))

qplot(user, count, data=count_group, geom="histogram", fill=group,
      xlab = "users", ylab="count") +
        opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90, hjust=0, size=7)) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = c(blues(10), reds(10)))
# blues(10) and reds(10) because you want blues for the first ten
#  groups, and reds thereafter. Each of these functions are equivalent
#  to providing vectors containing ten hex colors representing a gradient
#  of blues and a gradient of reds.
```

[image: ggplot with blues and reds]

Comment: thanks @jbaums, now I have another question, is it possible to separate the color scale into two parts and then color lets say groups from A to K one type of colors (blue palette) and from K to T another type (red palette)?

Comment: sure, by specifying two `colorRampPalette`s. I'll add it to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

An update on jbaums's answer. As far as I can make out, with the new ggplot2 (as of March 2014), the following syntax is available:

```
p <- qplot(user, count, 
  data = count_group, 
  geom = "histogram", 
  stat = "bin2d",
  fill = group,
  xlab = "users", 
  ylab = "count"
)
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0, size = 7))
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = cols(ngroups))
p
```

This was a little long for a comment, but it's not a full answer, the rest of the code is as given by jbaums, who must be thanked!